# Get draggable element position relative to dom

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a way to let a user to drag&drop a html element (lets say a div) and to position it somewhere in the DOM structure of the current page.

The only way I found was to get the draggable element position based on x/y, any ideas how to know where it was "dropped" relative to other html dom elements?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post the code that you have already written for this so far.